# Facebook Login is not working even if I upgrade to https

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login, opencart2.x

Facebook recently enforced the use of HTTPS in their app settings. I installed SSL certificate and my [website](https://kaneeza.com) (opencart) works fine over https. I created a new facebook app, added https domain, added other requirements to make it public and then I put the App ID and secret into my application and I still get that taunting error notification from Facebook 
[image]

And In my app setting I am using https too

[image]

Still I am unable to login and keep getting that error
Anyone else came across such a case?

Comment: You are not redirecting to the HTTPS version, and there is no `Strict-Transport-Security`. That might be the problem.

Comment: you mean i need to mention redirect_url ? with https

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by mention redirect_url

Comment: see the edit above @MehdiBounya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem doesn't lie in the Facebook settings - you need to make sure you use HTTP in the redirect URI *in your code*.

Your Facebook login button has the following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=234600760430222&state=...&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.4.2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fkaneeza.com%2Findex.php%3Froute%3Daccount%2Fawesome_social_login_ozxmod%2Ffblogin&scope=email
```

Note the `redirect_uri=http...` bit.

Comment: Thanks, i see that now, how can i fix it. using a helper function to get value like $data['fb_login'] = $helper->getLoginUrl($this->url->link('account/awesome_social_login_ozxmod/fblogin'), $permissions);

Comment: I'm not enormously familiar with OpenCart's API. You'll have to either figure out how to make `$this->url->link` generate a HTTPS link, or use something like `preg_replace` to replace the `http://` with `https://`.

Comment: oh I did, changed the url but still its giving me error, too much annoyed since the new restrictions applied by FB